# Move left and right wheel on turtlebot gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Lately i learnt how to make a turtlebot in gazebo simulator, and moved it by using cmd_vel command.
the question is:

1. how can i move each wheels because i
   should move it by using trajectory
   planning?
2. can we move the turtle bot
   to a specific point does cmd_vel
   only move the robot "straight" and
   "circle"?
3. if i should make a
   "sinusoidal" path using the
   trajectory planning, can i use
   cmd_vel topic?

Thank you in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279985/move-left-and-right-wheel-on-turtlebot-gazebo/) by [JossiChrist](https://answers.ros.org/users/33238/jossichrist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1- using the cmd_vel topic you don't have to worry about moving the wheels individually, that is done for you.

2 - in order to move any robot to a specific point you must first know where it is and which way it is facing. You'll then need to plan a path which the robot must follow to arrive at the final goal point. This is a more complex process than simply issuing a cmd_vel message.

3 - the cmd_vel topic controls the speed and direction a robot should move in at **a specific point in time** by sending multiple varying cmd_vel messages over time you can make a robot follow a sinusoidal path or any other path for that matter.

Hope this clears some things up for you.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JossiChrist](https://answers.ros.org/users/33238/jossichrist/) on 2018-01-18**:\

1. how if i want to move the robot's direction?, i mean i want to control each wheel... for example (rospub -l /my_robot/rightWheel data "1.0")
2. do u have any reference about how can i move the robot to the specific point?
3. does cmd vel only make "circle" and "straight" path?